# How to integrate a function that is recursive?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm trying to write an acceleration function that takes drag into account in a very basic way. The basic function is:

$$a(v) = 5 - 0.1v$$

As velocity increases, acceleration decreases because of drag until acceleration is zero, and "terminal velocity" is reached. (I know this is a very barebones model of drag but it fits my purposes, for a game.)

My issue is I can't figure out how to get this as a function of time (in seconds). In the above equation units are in $m/s^2$.

As a function of time I get:

$$a(t) = 5-d(t)$$

where

$$d(t) = 0.1\int_0^t a(x)  dx$$

The main problem is that I can't figure out how to find the integral in d(t), which represents the function for drag. By integrating acceleration I want to get velocity, but since acceleration is dependent on velocity in $a(t)$, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: How did you get that? If you know that $a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt}$, then you should be able to see that $$\frac{1}{5-0.1v(t)}\frac{dv}{dt} = 1$$ Can you integrate that?

Comment: This is a well known problem - a linear first order differential equation with constant coefficients. Googe for that, or use the comment from @barnes , or wait a while for an answer. (If you were studying mathematics rather than writing a game this question would be downvoted for lack of effort.)

Comment: I'm still learning calculus so this is a bit confusing. I understand that $a(t)$ is the derivative of velocity but can't see how you got from that to the equation below, and I'm not sure how I would integrate that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the equation
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = 5 - 0.1v(t)$$
A simple rearrangement gives you:
$$\frac{1}{5 - 0.1v(t)}\frac{dv}{dt} = 1$$
Integrate this with respect to $t$:
\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{5-0.1v(t)}\frac{dv}{dt}\;dt=\int\;dt&\Longrightarrow -10\log(5-0.1v) = t + C_0 \\
&\Longrightarrow \log(5-0.1v) = -0.1t-0.1C_0 \\
&\Longrightarrow 5 - 0.1v = C_1e^{-0.1t} \\
&\Longrightarrow v = 50 + C_2e^{-0.1t}
\end{align}
where $C_2$ is an arbitrary constant. To obtain the value of the constant $C_2$, you simply set an initial condition for $v$, plug it in, and solve for $C_2$. For example, the initial condition $v(0) = 0$ yields:
$$v(0) = 50+C_2 = 0\Longrightarrow v(t) = 50 - 50e^{-0.1t}$$
You can then substitute this into your equation for $a(t)$ to obtain:
$$a(t) = 5-0.1(50-50e^{-0.1t})=5e^{-0.1t}$$

Comment: Nice, thanks for the explanation. I think I understand most of it.. you isolated 1 then integrated both sides. I have a few questions that are probably very basic: why does integrating v(t) yield t and what is the significance of $C_0$ changing to $C_1$ and etc.?

Comment: @BobBobingham It is the integral of $dt$ that yields $t$ on the right hand side, not the integral of $v(t)$. I would have just used the same symbol $C$ throughout for the arbitrary constant, but I didn't want to confuse you, so I used $C_0, C_1, C_2$ to show that these constants are different, but related ($C_2 = -10C_1 = -10e^{-0.1C_0}$).

Comment: Sorry I meant v(t) to v, not t. For the constants that makes sense though.

Comment: @BobBobingham If you know that $\int \frac{1}{x}\;dx = \log x$ and also know how to integrate using substitution, then it will become clear to you. If you haven't learned that yet, then you have something to look forward to!